# clear textbox not work

Tags: jquery, textbox

I'm trying to showing clear textbox if only we typing the text
why it didnt show the clear text when I type something on textbox

Is there any suggestion how to fix it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($('.txt-input').val().length === 0){
    $('.erase').hide();
  }
  else{
     $('.erase').show();
  };
  
  $(".erase").click(function(){
    $('.txt-input').val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="txt-input"/>
</form>
<p class="erase">clear</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a listener to listen the changes of the input field.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.txt-input').on('keyup', function(){
    if($(this).val().length === 0 ){
         $('.erase').hide();
    }else{
         $('.erase').show();
    }
  });

  $(".erase").click(function(){
    $('.txt-input').val('');
  });
});
```

Comment: I see, so it was trigger when we type then enter to condition, thanks for explaination